# Sharekit 2.0 Twitter send several images at once

Tags: ios, twitter, sharekit

Is there a way to send several images at once when using Sharekit 2.0 Twitter? By looking at docs it may seem that's not possible because when can share just one item at a time. I am correct? or there's another approach that I could try?.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, unfortunately. ShareKit can send only one pic at once. However, you might try to use shareKit's convenience methods

```
#import "SHKReadItLater.h" //include the service's header at the top of your class

// Create the item to share (in this example, a url)
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://getsharekit.com"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"ShareKit is Awesome!"];

// Share the item
[SHKReadItLater shareItem:item];
```

to send more pics silently using autoshare (see [FAQ](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/issues)). Make sure that you use pre-ios twitter (via setting in configurator), as ios twitter can not handle autoshare yet. I admit, this is not very nice solution, as you would have to create SHKItem and open separate connection for each image.